# Sort Records according to distance

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT p FROM public.project p LEFT JOIN public.quotes q ON p.id = q.project_id WHERE q.status = 'ACCEPTED' and EXISTS(SELECT distinct l AS l1 FROM Location l where postal_code = (SELECT postal_code FROM address WHERE id = p.address_id)  and calculate_distance(43.7731408,-79.2317523,l.latitude,l.longitude,'K') <= 10.0)
```

This query is returning the projects which are in radius of 10 KM from user.
User location is 43.7731408,-79.2317523.

calculate_distance(lat1, long1, lat2, long2, units) is the function which returns distance between two points.

Now have to sort that projects according to the distance.

```
SELECT p FROM public.project p LEFT JOIN public.quotes q ON p.id = q.project_id
    WHERE q.status = 'ACCEPTED' and EXISTS(SELECT distinct l AS l1 FROM Location l where postal_code =  
   (SELECT postal_code FROM address WHERE id = p.address_id)  and 
   calculate_distance(43.7731408,-79.2317523,l.latitude,l.longitude,'K') <= 10.0)  
   ORDER BY calculate_distance(43.7731408,-79.2317523,l1.latitude,l1.longitude,'K') DESC
```

Tried this but its not working

Projects that are nearest to the user should be displayed first.

Comment: If you sort by DESC then it will start from farthest to nearest. Isn't?

Comment: Another way is create table in memory " create table... ", put data and then "select... order by"

Comment: Please post your table schema

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the query could be simplified

```
SELECT distinct p.*
FROM public.project p
JOIN address a ON a.id = p.address_id
JOIN Location l1 ON l1.postal_code = a.postal_code 
   and calculate_distance(43.7731408,-79.2317523,l1.latitude,l1.longitude,'K') <= 10.0 
JOIN public.quotes q ON p.id = q.project_id and q.status = 'ACCEPTED' 
ORDER BY calculate_distance(43.7731408,-79.2317523,l1.latitude,l1.longitude,'K') DESC
```

I'm using inner JOIN instead of LEFT JOIN because OP WHERE references joined table columns without checking for NULL.